Is the drag coefficient linear with speed?
I made an RC-car and wanted to simulate the drag of it in Solidworks. But after I did my simulations I put my results in a graph, the drag is quadratic with speed but the drag coefficient $C_D$ is linear with speed. Could someone explain to me why this is the case or why my results are somehow wrong?

I did three simulations and also added 0. If I then add a trend line this looks like a quadratic function.

These results are very linear. Why is this?

Sounds like you're effectively/indirectly differentiating a quadratic function.

The drag force seems reasonable (i.e. quadratic function of speed).  How is the drag coefficient being calculated?  Thanks.

Drag coefficient should be a constant, otherwise it is not a coefficient. So your drag model is incorrect if you get a non-constant coefficient.

Related physics of drag coefficient.

Also read over dimensional analysis which came about from trying to analyze aerodynamic data just like this.

The drag coefficient is not linear with speed because of the drag-force formula, $$ F_d = C_d A \frac{\rho V^2}{2}$$ where, $F_d$ is the drag force in newtons, $A$ is the cross sectional area of the RC car, $\rho$ is the air density, and $V$ is the laminar velocity of the air moving around the car. Solve this for $C_d$ and you get, $$ C_d = \frac{2F_d}{A\rho V^2}$$
Note that there likely two forms of drag acting on the RC car: pressure friction and skin friction. Defining your RC car's surface area and curvy geometry may be a feature in solidworks, otherwise calculating this to find the car's parasitic drag would be extremely hard. Why your drag coefficient-to-velocity graph is linear must be mistake, as it looks a lot like $\frac{\mathrm{d} F_d}{\mathrm{d} V}$ instead of a derivative of an inverse quadratic, $C_d$. I approximate the data to be something like,
$$C_{d}=\frac{.73}{15}V$$ and, $$F\left(V\right)=\left(\frac{.73}{15}\right)\frac{V^{2}}{10}$$ Do you have the generated functions for these?
